# Camel route to Websphere MQ , read interval

Tags: apache-camel, activemq-classic, ibm-mq

I use camel route in ActiveMQ in order to read message from websphere MQ queue and to forward the messages into a activeMQ queue, it works fine but it seems that the wmq read action is too often (every 1 secs).
How to define a read interval value ? for example read messages every 10 secs ?

Tks a lot
Nicolas

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the `receiveTimeout` and `requestTimeoutCheckerInterval` of JmsComponent which is used for MQ endpoints. By default these values are 1 sec.

Refer: - http://camel.apache.org/jms.html

Comment: On MQ Server side, the "read" is done by camel every 5 secs even if I override those two values to 180000ms ... I don't understand

Comment: FYI my route is the following : <route>
                <from uri="wmq:queue:MQQ"/>
            <setExchangePattern pattern="InOnly"/>
            <to   uri="activemq:queue:ACQ"/>
        </route>

Comment: Can you provide some information about the channel "CH" which you are using to connect to Websphere MQ. May be there is some KeepAlive (KAINT) or HeartBeat(HBINT) setup on the channel configuration.

Comment: Also are you sure you have tried changing the polling interval and rescan interval as suggested by other answer. The MQ docs states that the default intervals are 5 secs. https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/ae/umj_pjcfm_advprops.html

Comment: I changed the pollingInterval on my client side but same problem, and I don't have access to the MQ Server configuration, it's in the hand of my provider.

Answer (score -1):

It seems a wrong way to change jms component settings for changing read queue interval.

Spring JMS that used as underlying technology for Camel jms component are designed to polling queue often. 
Changing polling interval for jms endpoints need a deep understanding internals of Spring JMS. My experiments with this approach do not get any positive results.

Another way satisfies your requirements is a polling consumer. The idea is periodically run queue reading operation with timer (or another scheduler like quartz).

```
from("timer://foo?period=5000").bean("queueReader")
```

queueReader bean should implements queue reading operation.

But this approach have some pifalls. One of them is how to handle situation when queue have more than one messsage. This requires to loop queue reading, but new messages can arrive when existing ones worked on. This sitation need low level and error prone coding.

You would read details about polling consumer in Camel [here](http://camel.apache.org/polling-consumer.html)